# Can't find variable: StageWebViewBridge

Tags: flex4, stagewebviewbridge

I use the development tools:Adobe Flash Builder 4.6;

When I move the 'ExampleCallBackFuncions?.html' to an online server and try to load it using:

webView.loadURL("http://192.168.1.101/MapTest/ExampleBasic.html");

The html page appears but when I press the callAS3Function button I get the following error:

ReferenceError?: Can't find variable: StageWebViewBridge? callAs3Funciton at http://www.myserver.com/ExampleCallBackFuncions.html : 14 
onclick at http://www.myserver.com/ExampleCallBackFuncions.html : 27

Create flex mobile project is how to interact with , and I can not always interact?

Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the project:

http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/

It seems the file `StageWebViewBridge.js` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

When we use stagewebviewbridge, we should include StageWebViewBridge.js file in our .html file, because, though the .js file we can make communication between as3 and js. So you could include the .js file location in your .html file.

You better to have the .js file as part of your [ MapTest ] directory, or refer .js from http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/